# Columns out of alignment on Titanium ios picker

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I am building an app for iOS using Titanium. I have a simple 2 column picker, but the data in the selected row is out of alignment with unselected data. This occurs in both columns. Here is an image of what is displayed:

http://s15.postimg.org/oxoff7kgb/picker.png

Here is my picker code:

```
var ntrplevelpicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
bottom:'0pt',
useSpinner: true,
});
ntrplevelpicker.selectionIndicator = true;

var ntrpmin = ["1.5","2.0","2.5","3.0","3.5","4.0","4.5","5.0","5.5","6.0","6.5","7.0"];
var ntrpmax = ["1.5","2.0","2.5","3.0","3.5","4.0","4.5","5.0","5.5","6.0","6.5","7.0"];
var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
for(var i=0, ilen=ntrpmin.length; i<ilen; i++){
var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
id:'0',
title: ntrpmin[i]
});
column1.addRow(row);
}
var column2 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
for(var i=0, ilen=ntrpmax.length; i<ilen; i++){
var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
    id:'1', 
    title: ntrpmax[i] 
});
column2.addRow(row);
}
ntrplevelpicker.add([column1,column2]);
```

I have used similar code for pickers in other areas in this app, but have not seen this problem.

Comment: It appears that the two column picker has the most pronounced offset. the other single column ones, the offset does occur but is less pronounced. In the 4 column picker, I am assuming because of space constraints, the offset can not be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its the iOS7's picker property to highlight the selected picker data, its also same for the native iOS programming as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error i see it was accepted but i cannot see a solution above.